# Markov Chains: Long Run Behavior

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

In a large metropolitian area, communters either deive along *(A)*, carpool *(C)* or take
public transportation *(T)*. A study showed that transportation changes according to the
following transition matrix:
$$
\begin{matrix}
& A & C & T\\
A & 0.8 & 0.15 & 0.05\\
C & 0.05 & 0.9 & 0.05\\
T & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.85
\end{matrix}
$$
In the long run what fraction of the communters will use the three types of transportations?

I know that this problem can be solved by finding the stationary distribution (as it exists and this matrix will tend to it), but that is a lengthy calculation and I have a theorem that says the stationary distribution $\pi(y)=\frac{1}{(E_{y}T_{y})}$. I am wondering if this method would be any easier/faster, and if so, how would I go about beginning this?

Comment: No, it's not any faster to relate the stationary distribution back to the return time. It's also really not that long of a calculation to get the stationary distribution. You have to solve a system of three equations. Since the equations are in fact redundant, you can neglect one of them. Then you just normalize.

Comment: If I'm solving by hand wouldn't I need to go through the whole $\pi*q=\pi$ calculation, which in a 3x3 matrix is kinda ugly?

Comment: That's right. But because you know the eigenvalue is $1$, you therefore know that there is a nontrivial kernel, so it's really a system of just two equations in three unknowns. It's not that bad.